# Javascript problems with dropdown return

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have multiple dropdowns on my site and I am trying to alter the code so that when the chosen product is clicked again, the dropdown resets (i.e. exits the dropdown). See here in the middle of the page: https://www.arieliandcompany.com/make-a-career-transition.html

I am not managing to find a solution that retains the functionality of changing between products on dropdown, or being able to enter the dropdown again after exiting.

I tried adding this line, which closed the dropdown, but it messed up other elements of the dropdown functionality as mentioned above:

`chosenProd.onclick = function(){showIndProd(0);};`

Would anyone be able to help??

```
function showIndProd(prodNum){
var indProgs = document.getElementsByClassName('indProg');
var indProgImgs = document.getElementsByClassName('indProgImg');
var indProgPs = document.getElementsByClassName('indProgP');
var progMores = document.getElementsByClassName('indProdMore');
var chosenProd = document.getElementById(["indProg"+prodNum]);
var chosenProdMore = document.getElementById(["indProdMore0"+prodNum]);
var closeBut = document.getElementById('closeProdsMore');

for (i = 0; i < indProgImgs.length; i++) {
    if (prodNum != 0){
        indProgs[i].style.opacity = "0.3";
        indProgImgs[i].style.height = "300px";
        indProgs[i].style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
        progMores[i].style.display = "none";



        chosenProd.style.opacity = "1";
        chosenProd.style.filter = "none";
        chosenProdMore.style.display = "block";
        closeBut.style.display = "inline-block";    
        closeBut.style.position = "relative";
        chosenProd.onclick = function(){showIndProd(0);};




    } else { //close all and restore to default
        indProgs[i].style.opacity = "1";
        indProgImgs[i].style.height = "550px";
        indProgPs[i].style.display = "table";
        indProgs[i].style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
        progMores[i].style.display = "none";
        closeBut.style.display = "none";

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If anyone could help with this that would be great - problem is still unsolved!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with these two line

```
var chosenProd = document.getElementById(["indProg"+prodNum]);
var chosenProdMore = document.getElementById(["indProdMore0"+prodNum]);
```

Instead of passing string you are passing array

Comment: Hi brk, thanks for this. Actually this code works perfectly fine -- I actually want to **add** a line to this code to make the chosen product exit the dropdown on click, and that's what I'm having trouble with.